# Groovy: How is delegate of a closure set when adding a method on a metaclass of one class?

Tags: dynamic, groovy

In the following code `delegate` refers the `List` instance on which the closure is called. How was it set?

```
List.metaClass.removeRight = { int index ->
    delegate.remove(delegate.size() - 1 - index)
}
```

Comment: It is set when the meta method is invoked. Does that answer the question?

Comment: @tim_yates `this` and `owner` appear to refer to `ConsoleScript7@5e3eed51`. I'm wondering why `delegate` which is supposed to be the same as `owner` unless changed is equal to the list instance the meta method is invoked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MOP is responsible for dispatching method invocations to the closure.  It (the MOP) retrieves the closure from the metaClass, clones it, sets the delegate to be the object that the method was invoked on, and then invokes the closure.

Comment: Thanks! Why clone the closure?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel The closure has to be cloned because some state is going to be changed on it (the delegate will be assigned).  If it weren't cloned and you had 2 separate threads invoking the same method, the closure would share a delegate, which would be bad.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-pg06239/) is nice article on the topic. Especially *Closures and the ExpandoMetaClass* section.

I suppose that `this` and `owner` is `ConsoleScript7@5e3eed51` because it's *where* the closure is declared. 
Why delegate is equal to the list instance is well described in the mentioned article. Every class has an *ExpandoMetaClass* instance that surrounds it. This enables meta programming (e.g. adding methods, even if class is marked final), because method is being added to EMC which intercepts the call. A call hits the EMC first but it also needs access to surrounded instance and here's why the delegate is set to surrounded instance.

`delegate` is set exactly in [this](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/metaclass/ClosureMetaMethod.java) (line 77) class when the added method is invoked. For the method You added an instance of `ClosureMetaMethod` is created and registered with MOP. When it gets invoked the delegate is set to the object passed on which it's invoked. Is that now clear for You?

Comment: Great. But `delegate` needs to be explicitly set to change, right?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Otherwise it wouldn't work. I suppose it's being set during the construction of the closure. For further details sources need to be investigated.

Comment: So who sets the `delegate` of the closure. A method in *ExpandoMetaClass*?

Comment: @Opal "I suppose it's being set during the construction of the closure." - No.  That cannot be made to work.  The delegate needs to be set to the particular instance that the method was invoked on.  That instance may not even exist when the closure is constructed.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, You're definitely right. Have just found code in groovy sources that is responsible for setting the delegate in closure. Thanks!